# Scraping JS rendered page using Requests_HTML is not working as expected

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am working on Scraping a JS rendered page ( https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=Acer+Laptops ). In this page the product images are being loaded dynamically. The pre-rendered SRC values for these images is

> //img1a.flixcart.com/www/linchpin/fk-cp-zion/img/placeholder_9951d0.svg

After rendering, the SRC should be something like this

> https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/312/312/kcp4osw0/computer/f/w/d/acer-na-thin-and-light-laptop-original-imaftrdmuyxq5nrf.jpeg?q=70

Using requests_html  I can get the SRC values BUT it is only working for the first few images at the top. Please help me out here? My code :-

```
res = session.get("https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=Acer+Laptops")
res.html.render()
all_results = res.html.find('#container > div > div.t-0M7P._2doH3V > div._3e7xtJ > div._1HmYoV.hCUpcT > div:nth-child(2)', first=True) #Container for all the results
items = all_results.find('._1UoZlX') # Container for each product being displayed
for item in items:
   item_image = item.find('div._3BTv9X img', first=True).attrs.get('src')
   print(item_image)
```

Output:-

```
https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/312/312/kamtsi80/computer/m/8/y/acer-na-gaming-laptop-original-imafs5prytwgrcyf.jpeg?q=70
https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/312/312/kcp4osw0/computer/f/w/d/acer-na-thin-and-light-laptop-original-imaftrdmuyxq5nrf.jpeg?q=70
//img1a.flixcart.com/www/linchpin/fk-cp-zion/img/placeholder_9951d0.svg
//img1a.flixcart.com/www/linchpin/fk-cp-zion/img/placeholder_9951d0.svg
```

As you can see the first two images are loaded, the rest are not.
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: The image download and rendering seems to get triggered only after you scroll down and the images get displayed. I Never used requests, but selenium and/or phanthomjs can do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, as the images were lazily loaded I had to use "scrolldown" and "sleep" parameters in the "render()" function. Find the code below:

```
res = session.get("https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=Acer+Laptops")
res.html.render(scrolldown=20, sleep=.1)
all_results = res.html.find('#container > div > div.t-0M7P._2doH3V > div._3e7xtJ > div._1HmYoV.hCUpcT > div:nth-child(2)', first=True) #Container for all the results
items = all_results.find('._1UoZlX') # Container for each product being displayed
for item in items:
   item_image = item.find('div._3BTv9X img', first=True).attrs.get('src')
   print(item_image)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
import re


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    match = [x.group(1) for x in re.finditer(
        'dynamicImageUrl":"(.*?)"', r.text)]
    print(match)


main("https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=Acer+Laptops")
```

Output:

```
['http://rukmini1.flixcart.com/flap/{@width}/{@height}/image/c9ef9eae08a3b038.jpg?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}', 'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/{@width}/{@height}/promos/21/07/2017/e8625e14-3277-4f16-a4d4-df8ed525905b.png?q={@quality}']
```

Now you can replace **width**, **height** and **quality** according to your needs.

Defaults is 312 x 312 x 70

Comment: Is `dynamicImageUrl' a common tag or did you inspect the html to find it?

Comment: @RichieV **dynamicImageUrl** count as `key` of `JSON` dict which presented within page source.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working. All the images seem to be the same even though differently named.